# Unexpected behavior when implementing click outside

Tags: typescript, frontend, vuejs3

I'm implementing a simple click-outside feature, which closes the component with an editing field. For that I'm adding a click event listener to the root element and trying to see if the clicked element (event target) is a descendant of it. The problem is that the clicked event target happens to be the very button that switches the component to show. So the component shows up and immediately disappears.

[Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) (see added console logs)

How come it works like that? The component that adds a click event listener should do so after the button is clicked and the component is mounted.

`setTimeout` fixes the problem but I still can't wrap my head around why it's working like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a `vuejs` expert, so I can't say with certainty what part of the vue lifecycle happens synchronously. It certainly looks like the `mount` (that is triggered by the button click) is performed before the bubbling event reached the document root.

I can think of several potential fixes:

1. move the button inside the TitleEdit component, being its only visible element in the intial state. The button will no longer be outside the `this.$refs.container` element and the problem is fixed elegantly.
2. call `stopPropagation` on the click event. I strongly advise against this. Because this will lead to buggy behavior as soon as other parts of your UI rely on bubbling events reaching the document root. I.e. as soon as you use the combination of button and TitleEdit component a second time in the same view. ( I covered this topic some time ago in a [blog article](https://dev.to/teetotum/a-clean-approach-to-dom-event-cancellation-11m3) )
3. introduce a custom flag to the click event to signal to your root event handler to ignore this specific event:

   ```
    @click="editing = true; $event.titleEditIgnore = true;"
   ```

   ```
    cancelOnClickOutside (event: MouseEvent): void {
      if (event.titleEditIgnore === true)
        return;

      const clickedInside = this.$refs.container.contains(event.target)
      console.log('event target: ', event.target)
      !clickedInside && this.cancel()
    }
   ```

   But this solution is flawed, because as soon as you use a second pair of button and edit component, either edit buttons would not count as outside clicks to either of the edit components.

   (The reason I would not use `defaultPrevented` here is because that is used to signal that an event has already been handled (e.g. a clicked `<a>`) to event handlers that only act on unhandled events. Which is not the case with your outside click detector).
4. have your outside click detector listen during the `capture` phase; so it will have missed the capturing phase for the button click and ignore the bubbling click.

   ```
    mounted (): void {
      console.log('registered event handler')
      document.addEventListener('click', this.cancelOnClickOutside, { capture: true })
    },
    unmounted (): void {
      console.log('removed event handler')
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.cancelOnClickOutside, { capture: true })
    },
   ```

   This might solve the issue, but I would not consider this a very clear solution. It has the potential to be confusing for other maintainers.

If I had to choose I would go with solution #1, and if that is not possible with solution #4.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. #1 and #4 may be fine indeed. Delaying attaching of the event handler with `setTimeout` works as well. Still can't figure out why Vue works like that, though. It's very confusing and counter-intuitive.